# Using Service to check if User has valid session in Android

Tags: android, service

At this Point My App looks like follows:

`SplashScreen` -> `LogInScreen` -> `TextActivity`

In LogInScreen I check if the User is still active(means is already logged in) or has a valid session and if it is okay, then start the next Activity.

Now I want to change it like:
`SplashScreen` -> `TextActivity`

And while the User is working in `TextActivity`. I want to check with a `Service`, if the User has to log in again (maybe if he hasn't logged in for a while).

Is, using a `Service`, the right way to do it?
And can I close all `Activity`s and start the `LogInScreen` if the User has to log in again?

I've read in the Documentary that a `Service` is still in progress even if the called Activity is destroyed. But I can't return something from the Service is that right?

How it's clear what I want to do.

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend a service to run as a background task, this will consume memory for almost nothing.

I assume your Login part sends a request to a server to get credentials and then log your user to the app. 
So basically I assume you have a server and you are sending requests and getting response from the server.

To check if the user has a valid session, you just have to check if the session has expired from server response.

Comment: Thats the way I do it at this time. So what would you recomment to check if the user has a active session in the background? just a asynctask?

Answer (score 0):

Use Shared Preference this will solve your issue once and for all.

First of all if you are using server authentication for user login then request the server for authentication and get back the result with it's id or password and set to the Shared Preference and while accessing the app next time check the values are set for shared preference or not if it is set then start your next activity.

```
 sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//        Checking values for Keys Keyname, Keypass, Keyemail if available then get the strings values and set to respective EditTexts.

    if(sharedpreferences.contains("Keyname") && sharedpreferences.contains("Keypass") && sharedpreferences.contains("Keyemail"))
    {
      // start your activity herein
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Shared Preference not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

that's it.

only one time login will be there.